# I am unable to build mongodb-binding with YCSB

Tags: mongodb, maven, ycsb

I am trying to build mongodb-async driver with YCSB (0.15.0) version. I am running it on Clear Linux OS, and have MONGODB version 4.0.5 and mvn -version is 3.6.0.

I am running the command "mvn -pl com.yahoo.ycsb:mongodb-binding -am clean package" from my home directory of YCSB, and get the following error:

Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yahoo.ycsb:mongodb-bindin
g:jar:0.16.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.allanbank:mongodb-async-driver:jar:2.10.1: Failed to read artifact des
criptor for com.allanbank:mongodb-async-driver:jar:2.10.1: Could not transfer artifact com.allanbank:mongodb-async-driver:pom:2.10.
1 from/to allanbank (http://www.allanbank.com/repo/): Connect to www.allanbank.com:80 [www.allanbank.com/206.210.70.161] failed: Co
nnection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]

Can someone please point me what might be going wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to configure the JAVA_HOME in the .mavenrc by adding:
expot JAVA_HOME=your path (eg: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/) into this file

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem was wrong protocol in the maven/settings.xml. I mixed up <id> and <protocol> tag.